# How to sync a software project between computers?

Tags: git, version-control

Of course, I'm using git for version control, which also serves (to an extent) to keep different computers in sync. Now consider this scenario: I've been working on some big changes on my computer, but I need to leave and want to continue on my laptop. But the code is broken in its current state; it might not even compile.

If I'm working all alone with a private repository I guess I could just go ahead and commit the mess to continue the work on my laptop. It does have a bad smell though.

But if I'm working with a team on the same repository that's a no-go. A branch might save me here, but that still smells like a workaround.

I've also thought of using a synchronization application like Syncthing, but I'm afraid that two different synchronization applications might bite each other at some point. I wouldn't forgo git when using Syncthing.

I'm aware that this question will likely not result in one single correct answer. But I think that this a common scenario programmers might face and hope that different ideas on how to deal with it will be considered helpful for the community.

Comment: A branch is exactly how one would track changes toward a feature before it's ready to be merged back into the codebase.  Why exactly are you against using a branch?

Comment: @David: because I think that even to a branch one shouldn't commit some unfinished mess. Even in a branch commits should be whole in its own right and should represent completed units of work. And for the very least: they should be compilable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The view that some stuff is "too messy to be committed and pushed" is really hamstringing yourself. Git is your best tool for moving software changes from place to place, it's a tool you already have, and it's designed to enable a "commit early, commit often" mindset. My recommendation is to use it.

If you're worried that collaborators or CI pipelines will be tempted to treat your branch as something that's ready for their eyes, when it's actually a big mess, I recommend *namespacing* your branches. You could give all work-in-progress branches a `WIP/` prefix, or have a `people/username/` prefix for each developer, with the understanding that what goes on there is experimental, may not compile, may be force-pushed at any time, shouldn't be used as the base for any other branch, etc.

Then, do what you want. If you're in the middle of some work and your train is coming, do a
`git commit -anm WIP ; git push` and go home. After pulling somewhere else you can use a "soft" `git reset` to get the changes in your working directory while pretending that that commit never existed, and then you can commit your work in a more orderly fashion when it's ready, and force-push. Or you can use `git rebase --interactive` later to accomplish pretty much the same thing.

These are my opinions, but I think that if you have a good tool available, you should use it, and as long as you're doing honest work and not misleading anyone (which is where namespacing helps), you don't need to be ashamed of your false starts.

Comment: Agreed.  It took me a few years of using git before I realized that commits and branches are your friends.

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned in your question, there are several ways in which you can do this.

**Option 1**

The easiest one would be to use git. Create a branch in the repository that sits in your computer, let's call that branch `my_feature`. Once you have the branch in place:

- commit and push the changes you have done in your computer, even if they do not work/compile

```
git checkout my_feature
...work work work
git add .
git commit -m'My incomplete work from my computer...'
```

- go to your laptop and pull your branch `my_feature`

```
git fetch
git checkout -b my_feature origin/my_feature (use -b only the first time you run this command)
```

- work in your laptop. One you are done, commit and push your changes

```
git add .
git commit -m'My incomplete work from my laptop...'
git push origin my_feature
```

- go back to your computer, pull the latest changes from branch `my_feature`

```
git checkout my_feature
git pull
```

- repeat until work is done

The only caveat of these steps is that you will create commits that contain code that doesn't "work". This is actually not a problem because once your branch `my_feature` is done and the code is as you want it to be, you can do things like squashing the commits, or rebasing them to reorganise the commits as you need.

I would not recommend you use a sync tool unless you understand very well how git works under the hood and you know what you are doing. If you do not sync correctly, you can end up with a corrupted repository (I'm not saying that you cannot do it, just that you have to do it properly).

**Option 2**

Another option, using also git, would be to use forks. You create a private fork and add it as a second remote. Then you push everything to that fork. Once the work is done, you can rebase and/or squash the commits before merging them in the upstream repository.